# mathjax not working when url change in spa

Tags: mathjax

I'm using Mathjax to display equations in a web application done in Nextjs. The equations are rendered correctly when the page is loaded first.But when user links to other route with `Link`, the new page display the latex code.But if i refresh the page, then the equations are rendered correctly.How can i solve this issue?

Comment: How are you typesetting with MathJax? Do you use a package?

Comment: If a page is modified after MathJax does its initial typesetting run, you have to tell MathJax to typeset the new material.  See the [documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/typeset.html) for v3, or if you are using v2 [this page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/advanced/typeset.html).